# Haskell comment syntax not being highlighted

Tags: bug, status-norepro, syntax-highlighting

Here is a sample Haskell code block:

```
 -- This is a comment <- notice how this is syntax highlighted as though it were code
 {- This is also a Haskell comment -}

 // This isn't even a comment in Haskell, it's a syntax error.
 # This isn't a comment either.
 -- // Only this is a comment to both Haskell and SO's syntax highlighter.

 -- Some actual Haskell code:
 f :: a -> a
 f x = x

 -- Some more actual Haskell code:
 f' :: (a -> a') -> [a -> a] -> a -> a'
 f' f0 fs = foldl' (.) f0 fs
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing much better than VB - `'` really messes the formatting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6812/7586 . Anyway, assuming there's no AI code that can detect the language, what are you suggesting? `--` is also an SQL comment, but it can be tricky separating it from the decrement operator.

Comment: Maby read in two words. And if second word is alphanumeric, parse it as haskell?

Comment: @Kobi: No actually it's worse. `'` in Haskell is a character that can present in an identifier, so we can't use the "close the comment" trick in VB.

Comment: is the space after the double hyphens required? Would sure make things easier

Comment: [According to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/131713), Haskell (`lang-hs`) is now explicitly supported.

Comment: By the way, is `lang-hs` it the same as `lang-haskell`? Also, `haskell` seems to produce different results than `lang-haskell`—what's with that?

Comment: @ErikAllik See [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224611/haskell-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

The questions are all tagged with the language, right?  So they could use the tags to determine which highlighting quirks to enable.

Comment: This won't work. Say if a post is tagged [python] and [haskell] for comparing / translating some language constructs, what language should the code apply? Or if the question is [language-agnostic]?

Comment: If it's language agnostic they can just do what they do now.  If it's got multiple language tags, maybe then it should also just do what it does now.  But if it's got one language tag I don't think it would hurt to improve the highlighting a little.

Comment: @KennyTM I think that's a relatively rare edge case, and as bemace points out, it wouldn't hurt if implemented reasonably.

Answer (score 1):

There is no consistent syntax highlighting on StackOverflow.  While prettify.js, the syntax highlighting mechanism it uses, does support a lot of languages, there is currently no way for an author to get the language tag through to that script.  Haskell is only one of many languages that suffer from this.  In guess-mode, prettify.js seems to lean strongly towards languages with syntax similar to C.

It seems that something like `<code class="prettyprint lang-haskell">` could be put on the HTML whitelist for Markdown, but this proposal has gone unanswered for over a year now.  See for example this question: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints).