# Haskell Syntax Highlighting

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68443/haskell-comment-syntax-not-being-highlighted/) and have the same question as commenter Erik: why does `<!-- language: lang-haskell -->` highlighting:

```haskell
{-# a pragma #-}
{- a comment -}
-- a comment
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Foo

main =
    let y = Bar $ Qux $ U.replicate 11221184 0 :: Foo (Qux Int)
        (Bar (Qux ans)) = iterate (plus y) y !! 100
    in putStr $ show $ foldl1' (*) ans
```

differ from `<!-- language: lang-hs -->` or `<!-- language: haskell -->` highlighting:

```hs
{-# a pragma #-}
{- a comment -}
-- a comment
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Foo

main =
    let y = Bar $ Qux $ U.replicate 11221184 0 :: Foo (Qux Int)
        (Bar (Qux ans)) = iterate (plus y) y !! 100
    in putStr $ show $ foldl1' (*) ans
```

I'm trying to figure out how the styles are differentiated so I can send bug reports to the right ones, as recommended in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/181417). It would also be nice to know, as a commenter on the answer suggested, if [google-code-prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/) is dead.

Why are there multiple Haskell styles? Are there simply multiple highlighters in google-code-prettify, or is there some other reason? How does SO choose which highlighter to use by default (when the question is tagged, for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlighting you get with `lang-haskell` is the same as you get with, for example, `lang-unicorns`:

```unicorns
{-# a pragma #-}
{- a comment -}
-- a comment
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Foo

main =
    let y = Bar $ Qux $ U.replicate 11221184 0 :: Foo (Qux Int)
        (Bar (Qux ans)) = iterate (plus y) y !! 100
    in putStr $ show $ foldl1' (*) ans
```

It's the default highlighting you get when the language key you used isn't in fact defined. `lang-hs` is defined and gives you Haskell-specific highlighting.

When you use `language: tagname` (rather than `lang-foo`), the highlighter used is the one that is associated with the tag (`lang-hs` here).

Yes, the highlighter settings are derived from the question's tags.