# WMD/Prettify does not support dot character for XML elements

Tags: bug, status-deferred, editor, syntax-highlighting, xml

The WMD (or possibly Prettify)  does not support the dot (.) character for elements, despite it being part of the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e804). This comes up on StackOverflow with XAML related questions.

Below is an example of the rendering of an element and attribute, both with a "." in their name. Notice that ".suffix" is coloured incorrectly.

```
<prefix.suffix />
```

(As a new user on this site I cannot mark this question as 'xml' or 'xaml', as was my intention)

Comment: I suspect this is due to Prettify, not WMD. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Good call - I've updated the question

Comment: @Richard - I've added the 'xml' tag for you.

Answer (score 3):

The code tag has never been intended to understand or support all languages. It does a good job on some, and some have problems. Like VB, Perl (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/improve-the-code-tag-highlighting)). You can find many request when searching the [syntax-highlighting tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting).

As it is [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) used, feel free to contact the project.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed at revision 93 of prettify.js: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/diff?spec=svn93&r=93&format=side&path=/trunk/src/prettify.js

Answer (score 0):

We just deployed the latest trunk of prettify.js ; revision 83

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js