# Minor bug in VB.NET syntax highligting

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

When adding an inline comment to VB.NET code, the following lines are colored as strings:

```
dim a as integer
a += 1 'And here is the comment which turns the next line(s) into strings.
dim b as integer = a * 2
```

Comment: for some reason, the behaviour i'm describing was evident while writing the bug report, but not when viewing it.  To see it on a posted question, go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109302/how-to-read-ebcdic-data-with-a-non-standard-codepage-and-not-mess-up-numbers

Comment: Use two quotes `''` in your snippet to avoid this.

Comment: Hans - are you following me around and answering my questions ? :-)  Yes, the two quotes helped!

Comment: This is a duplicate...I'm just too lazy to look it up right now. And yes, it's the `'`, just add a closing one after the comment.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/vb-net-vbscript-syntax-highlighting-does-not-properly-support-comments) and duplicate [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/improve-the-code-tag-highlighting-closed)

Answer (score 2):

As long as your question is correctly tagged [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) it should be fine in the final question.

The preview will show a more generically rendered code preview, so don't hold that as gospel.